# Partition a dataframe with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
       vid   sid   pid  ts
1      101    123  ...
2      102    125
3      102    125
4      102    125
```

Essentially `vid` is a visitor `id` and `sid` is a session ID

I am trying to partition the df, which has a length of about 1.7 mil rows into smaller dataframes of about ~100k in length.

```
for i in range(0, len(df), s):
    sdf = df.iloc[i:i+s]
```

However, I **do not** want to slice the dataframe in the middle of a session (so where the last row in a sliced portion isn't the last.

For example, below would be a problem because it slices the dataframe where the session id `sid` is still occurring

```
         vid   sid   pid  ts
99999    101    144  ...
99999    102    145
100000   102    145
--------------------------
100001   102    145
```

I'm looking for some sort of way to make it such that if the cut off occurs where the `sids` are cut off, to simply push the cut off until the sids are no longer the same, like

```
for i in range(0, len(df), s):
    if i['sid'][-1] != (i+1)['sid']:
        sdf = df.iloc[i:i+s]
    else:
      # check until sessions are no longer equal
```

Comment: Did you try `value_counts` on `sid` column to evaluate the mean length of `sid` distribution? Maybe you can simply groupby on this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) for that

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df.set_index('sid'), npartitions=17).reset_index()
```

Note, that the number of partitions is not enforced to be always `17`. dask might decide to partition differently to keep indices in one partition - which is exactly what you want. Alternatively you could also specify a size or number of rows I think.

Then you could either get the partitions with something like

```
ddf.get_partition(3).compute()
```

or directly use dask for the distributed computing as that is what it was made for.

Comment: This seems like its working! Is there anyway I can iterate through all these dfs and apply a function and merge them all back together? I ask because I am transposing the data (df is too big to be transposed before being partitioned)? I imagine I can loop through the `get_partition()` method and apply the function to each and append/join them?

Comment: In principle Dask offers a subset of the pandas (and numpy) API which works automatically on all partitions. Do you only need to transpose the data and put it back together? Something like `ddf.to_dask_array().transpose` might be a good start. If you want to apply a functions to each row `ddf.apply(func, axis=1).compute()` should be all you need.

But to answer your question, I would need to know more about what you want to do :) It would be a good idea to open a new question for that.